# GUI tools for Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython

Is it possible to build Interactive application using Jupyter Notebook?? for example I want to a window frame with two icons for Image and Camera and I want to be call my Ipython program in it.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  The primary way to implement rich interactions in Jupyter is to use
widgets.

https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Please see https://github.com/AaronWatters/jp_proxy_widget for an easy
way to use general interactive Javascript in Jupyter notebook widgets.  Also see
https://github.com/AaronWatters/jp_doodle for some components built using proxy widgets that support complex visualizations with mouse interactions and animation.